# Why do I get this "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to write a small program that
does the following:
[it should draw many small triangles which are lined up and have different colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CjT7.png).

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

I have already looked a bit on the internet but I could not fix my error

This is my code:

```
from turtle import *
from random import *


def triangleDrawer():
   fd(20)
   rt(120)
   fd(20)
   rt(120)
   fd(20)
   rt(120)
   fd(20)

colors  = ["red","green","blue","orange","purple","pink","yellow"]

def pictureDrawer():
   i = 1
   jumper = 10
   x = -200
   y = 200
   up()
   goto(x, y)
   down()
   while i<100:
      triangleDrawer()
      currentColor = random.choice(colors)
      color(currentColor)
      if(i == jumper):
         y = y - 18
         up()
         goto(x, y)
         down()
         jumper += 10
      i+=1
     
pictureDrawer()
```

Comment: Because you did `from random import *` so `random` is really `random.random`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this import:

```
from random import *
```

You import `random.random` as `random` and try to use it as the module.
You also import `random.choice` as `choice` this way so its available as `choice`.

Either use:

```
import random
```

Which will namespace everything under `random` as you expect.

**Or** use `choice` instead of `random.choice`:

```
currentColor = choice(colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error;  `import random as random` did the job.

Comment: Just use `import random`